# Is there a name for a set together with a unary operation?

Tags: terminology

Is there a name for a set together with a unary operation?

If so, where can I learn more about them? Is there anything interesting about them? Are they simply a special case of groups? It simply occurred to me and Googling around has failed me.

Comment: It is called a function from the set to itself....

Comment: You might also be interested in [involutions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Involution_%28mathematics%29). They tend to appear in all sorts of algebraic situations. See also [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semigroup_with_involution).

Comment: From [Wikipedia/Outline of algebraic structures#Simple structures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outline_of_algebraic_structures#Simple_structures): "Unary system: S and a single unary operation over S."

Comment: I think some people define discrete dynamical systems that way.

Comment: Maybe just an endomorphism?

Answer (score 1):

They are called **monounary algebras** for example in this paper:

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/225623822_Monounary_algebras

Answer (score 0):

I have seen the term "unoid" - a set with several unary operations - in the book "Algebraic Systems" by A.I. Mal'cev.
So "1-unoid" can be an answer.

The theory of 1-unoids is not entirely devoid. For example, it contains the Recursion Theorem:
https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Principle_of_Recursive_Definition

Answer (score 0):

They're called "unary systems"